# how to check a string is a url through apex code

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I have a vf page and a controller, i am using apex:inputext for text box on vf page, now i want my vf to accept only url type text, what should i do?
I tried for some Javascript, but I want add logics in apex not in javascript, so that i can show similar page error for all error types.

Page:

```
    <apex:page docType="HTML-5.0" controller="AdminPannelController" id="pgId">
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.ColorPicker}" />
    <script>
    function func(){
        if({!!flag}){
            alert('Successfully uploaded');
        }
    }
    function loadValue(){
        document.getElementById('pgId:frmId:pgBlockId:pbsection:valueInput').value =  document.getElementById('valueInput').value;
    }fragment locator
        return pattern.test(str);
    }
<apex:form id="frmId" >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Live Agent Configure " id="pgBlockId">
            <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbsection" columns="2">
            <apex:outputLabel value="Text Url: ">
                    <apex:inputText value="{!textUrl}" />
                </apex:outputLabel>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Bottom" id="pbButton">
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Reset" action="{!reset}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons> 
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class AdminPannelController{
    public Document file{get;set;}
    public string textUrl{get;set;}
 public void save(){
List<brand__mdt> productNameFromMetaData = [Select DeveloperName from brand__mdt where id =: metaData limit 1];
        List<Folder> existingFolder = [Select Id,Name from Folder where Name = 'Product Logo Folder' limit 1];
        List<Folder> existingTextFolder = [Select Id,Name from Folder where Name = 'Product Text Folder' limit 1];      

        Document Doc = new Document();
        try{
            List<AdminPanelBranding__c> existingColorCode = [Select Background_Color__c from AdminPanelBranding__c where Name =: productNameFromMetaData[0].DeveloperName ];
            if(colorCode == ''){
                if(existingColorCode.size() > 0){
                    colorCode = existingColorCode[0].Background_Color__c;
                }
            }
            List<Document> existingDoc = [Select Name,Id,Body from Document where Description =: metadata AND FolderId =: existingFolder[0].id limit 1];

            if(file.Name == null){
                if(existingDoc.size() > 0){
                    Doc.id = existingDoc[0].id;
                    Doc.name=existingDoc[0].Name;
                    Doc.Body=existingDoc[0].Body;
                    Doc.Description = metadata;
                    Doc.Folderid = existingFolder[0].id;
                    update Doc;
                }
            }
            else{
                if(existingDoc.size() > 0){
                    Doc.id = existingDoc[0].id;
                    Doc.name=file.Name;
                    Doc.Body=file.Body;
                    Doc.Description = metadata;
                    Doc.Folderid = existingFolder[0].id;

                    if(file.BodyLength <= 135000 ){
                        update Doc;
                        flag = false;
                    }
                    else{
                        flag = true;
                        ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error: Invalid Text Document , Please upload a Text/Plain Document with less than 135kb size');
                        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
                    }
                }
                else{

                    Doc.name=file.Name;
                    Doc.Body=file.Body;
                    Doc.Description = metadata;
                    Doc.Folderid = existingFolder[0].id;

                    if(file.BodyLength <= 135000 ){

                        insert Doc;
                        flag = false;
                    }
                    else{
                        flag = true;
                        ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error: Invalid Text Document , Please upload a Text/Plain Document with less than 135kb size');
                        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
                    }
                }
            }
        }Catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
        finally {
            file.Body = null;
        }

        AdminPanelBranding__c csetting = new AdminPanelBranding__c();
        csetting.Background_Color__c = colorCode;
        csetting.Logo__c = Doc.id;
        cSetting.Text__c = textUrl;
        csetting.Name = productNameFromMetaData[0].DeveloperName;

        List<AdminPanelBranding__c> existingCsetting = [Select Name,Logo__c,Background_Color__c,Text__c from AdminPanelBranding__c where Name =: productNameFromMetaData[0].DeveloperName limit 1];

        if(existingCsetting.size() == 0 ){
            insert csetting;
        }
        else{
            csetting.id = existingCsetting[0].id;
            update csetting;
        }
        callfunc='<script> func(); </script>';
    }

    public PageReference reset() {
        PageReference newpage = new PageReference(System.currentPageReference().getURL());
        newpage.setRedirect(true);
        return newpage;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way you can verify upon creating URL object instance with that input url.

> **Following will throw exception as 'no protocol'**

```
String inputURL = 'www.google.com';
try
{
    URL urltest = new URL(inputURL);
}
catch(System.StringException e)
{
    System.debug(e.getMessage());
    throw new CustomException(e.getMessage());
}
```

> **Following will successfully pass**

Valid url = 'http://www.google.com;

```
String inputURL = 'http://www.google.com';
try
{
    URL urltest = new URL(inputURL);
    system.debug('valid');
}
catch(System.StringException e)
{
    System.debug(e.getMessage());
    throw new CustomException(e.getMessage());
}
```

> Otherwise, through **Pattern and Matcher**

```
// First, instantiate a new Pattern object "MyPattern"
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile('^((http|https)://)??(www[.])??([a-zA-Z0-9]|-)+?([.][a-zA-Z0-9(-|/|=|?)??]+?)+?$');

String inputURL = 'http://www.google.com';

// Then instantiate a new Matcher object "MyMatcher"
Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(inputURL);

// You can use the system static method assert to verify the match
System.debug('result=' + MyMatcher.matches());
if(!MyMatcher.matches())
{
    throw new CustomException('invalid url');
}
```

Comment: which one you have considered?

Comment: Last one **Pattern.compile()**